# Sorting XML data in PHP4

Tags: php, xml, php4

Hi there I have the following XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<connector_ret>
   <function name="search">
     <row id="1">
         <col id="1">AAA</col>
         <col id="2">243168</col>
         <col id="3">090828-000300</col>
         <col id="4">Subject</col>
     </row>
     <row id="2">
         <col id="1">BBB</col>
         <col id="2">243515</col>
         <col id="3">090831-000116</col>
         <col id="4">Subject</col>
     </row>
     <row id="3">
         <col id="1">BBB</col>
         <col id="2">244913</col>
         <col id="3">090905-000022</col>
         <col id="4">Subject</col>
     </row>
     <row id="4">
         <col id="1">CCC</col>
         <col id="2">245323</col>
         <col id="3">090907-000253</col>
         <col id="4">Subject</col>
     </row>
     <row id="5">
         <col id="1">CCC</col>
         <col id="2">245323</col>
         <col id="3">090907-000253</col>
         <col id="4">Subject</col>
     </row>
   </function>
</connector_ret>
```

I was wondering if it was possible to loop through this in PHP4 and only display certain rows when given a variable.

For example if the variable given is BBB then only display rows where the first column id is also equal to BBB.

So the output would be:

BBB - 243515 - 090831-000116 - Subject
BBB - 244913 - 090905-000022 - Subject

and the other rows are just ignored.

If the variable given is AAA the output would be:

AAA - 243168 - 090828-000300 - Subject

You get the idea :)

If you can help that'd be fantastic.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @Pete: just a remark PHP4 is dead so you should think about upgrading

Comment: Trust me it'd make things a lot easier but trying to get IT at work to switch to 5 is nearly impossible.

Comment: @Pete: I am pretty much in the same situation here, I have installed both PHP5/PHP4 on the webserver so at least every new stuff is in PHP5. The problem if you don't start you cannot migrate ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `xpath` to do such processing

```
$dom    =domxml_open_mem($xml); 
$calcX = &$dom->xpath_new_context();
$xml_parsed["match"]= node_content(
   $calcX->xpath_eval("//row/col[@id=1][text()='BBB']")
);
```

Comment: Are there any prerequisites to this?  I have a feeling IT have disabled the modules needed for this as PHP conks out as it runs the domxml_open_mem function.

Comment: yeah the domxml is a PECL extension, but on most modern distro (Ubuntu,debian,centos) you can install has a package, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxml.installation.php for PHP install

Comment: Thanks for that.  Is there any solution for this out of the box?  I'm afraid trying to get IT to add any addition extensions might have issues.  If not I guess that's the only way I can go about it.

Thanks again!

Comment: that's not the only way but after doing some reg exp parsing of XML/HTML is evil, so you better to get your sysroot moving.

Comment: Thanks Rage.  I'll definitely try the push to move forward.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You might look at XSL-T as your solution to this. It's easy enough to select the nodes you want and transform the results.

Comment: Problem is the XML is generated through a third-party API and as such I'm only able to work with what the XML output I have.

Comment: @Bernard: XSL-T is available out of the box only in PHP5 and for doing such things plain `Xpath` is enough IMHO